# mySQL $REQUEST defaults

Tags: mysql, html

mySQL NOOB question:

Table has a column = AgeGroup.  It is populated with the following data options: U40, 40-44, 45-49, 50-54, 55-59, 60+.

I have a form which allows the user to select the 'Gender' and 'AgeGroup' they wish to view.  This then uses a "WHERE" clause of "SELECT" SQL query. It uses in the following format:

```
FROM 
   #__test1
WHERE
   EventName = '2011EoSummer' AND
   Gender = {$REQUEST:Gender};
   if(isset($_REQUEST['Age'])) AND AgeGroup = {$_REQUEST['Age']}
```

In the form, there is a option to get all ages via "Overall" but there is no data called "Overall" in the AgeGroup column.  Overall should default to ALL age groups, but I don't know how this would read in the SQL query.

Example 1 URL: /&Gender=Men&AgeGroup=U40 => would display data in 'U40' 'Men'

Example 2 URL: /&Gender=Men&Age=Overall => would display ALL Age data

Comment: Can I see the PHP/whatever you are using to connect to the db as it would be easier to handle this within that.

Comment: It sounds like you want to generate an average age group, is this correct?

Comment: If you are preparing query on php side then just place condition and prepare query accordingly. Like for overall age group just don't place the `AgeGroup` clause in where condition. For all other option place it.

Comment: not looking for average.  Just want the AgeGroup clause removed when "Overall" is selected.  Can't do on PHP side.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm reading this right, when you have "overall" selected you want to return all the age groups (so as not to limit by any age group)?

If so you need to remove the AgeGroup clause in your SQL statment.

```
<?PHP

$sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE Gender = {$_REQUEST['gender']}";

if(isset($_REQUEST['age']))
{      
  $sql.= " AND AgeGroup = {$_REQUEST['age']}"
}

?>
```

This will default to overall, so you may want to change the logic appropriately, hope I got what you were after, if not ignore it!

Also as a side note $_REQUEST isn't the best to use, if your using a form as your action collector set it to post and use $_POST instead, if you cant use $_GET to pull your data out of the url instead of request.

Edit: Added in brackets to make it easier to read.

Comment: I'm sorry... a touch confused.  Here is what I have:
WHERE
    Gender = {$REQUEST:Gender} AND
    if(isset($_REQUEST['Age'])) AND AgeGroup = {$_REQUEST['Age']}

Which does not seem to work.. Thanks.

Comment: I think your trying to do the logic in the MySQL command? What server side language are you using?